# I am designing a Java Robot?

Tags: java, robotics

I am using a robot programmed with Java with a distance and touch sensor (but no gps or compass) to navigate a 1.0 by 2.5 metre obstacle course. The robot only knows its position by dead reckoning (like the number if turns of its wheels). When it turns it can measure the number of degrees from its last path travelled. After it finds the obstacles it needs to produce a map of where they are most likely to be. I want to extend a JPanel Class and override its paintComponent() method and then use the methods of the Graphics class to draw on the JPanel. I know that there are many drawxxxx methods for drawing. But I was wondering how I could actually achieve this, like the actual code that is necessary to produce this?!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Is it a physical robot or "software robot"?

Answer (score 0):

There's a great lesson on that on the official Java Swing tutorial page:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html